# How to select the max of revenue for each user_id with row number in SQL?

Tags: sql

In my dataset there are some user_id that each of them has several row number (from 1 to n) that each row has a specific revenue. I want to select the maximum of the revenue for each user_id with the row number belongs to this revenue. I want to have a query with result of the highlighted rows.

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.revenue = (select max(t2.revenue) from t t2 where t2.user_id = t.user_id);
```

If there are ties for the maximum, this returns all the highest value rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,
    case when revenue = max(revenue) over (partition by user_id) then 1 else 0 end as highlight
from T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tt.*
from #tbl tt
  join (select user_Id, max(revenue) as revenue from #tbl group by user_Id) tm on tt.user_Id = tm.user_Id and tt.revenue = tm.revenue
```

Comment: Thank you, what is this tm? I tried your code but I received error

Comment: tm it is just an alias for inner query, depends on your DB, maybe you should change it on "as tm"